Changing Mysql datadir to different disk
Followed this instructions but no luck, I cannot start mysql services
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-20-04
I'm new to ubuntu
fresh install ubuntu 24.04
Mysql 8.0.39
systemctl status mysql shows
usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre ( code=exited, status=0/success)
/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/failure)
status server shutdown complete
error 13 permission denied

where to start investigating ?
trying to learn ubuntu thanks
Edit:
new directory owner is already mysql:mysql with chmod 700 permission

I'm not sure if it helps, but my search gave that sudo journalctl -xe -u mysql may help you investigating with logs... Give it a try

To state the obvious : the instructions from a manual written for Ubuntu 20 may no longer be (completely) accurate for Ubuntu. - Also and in general : describe the steps you took in your question, rather then making us guess where the manual you followed might be wrong or if the issue is (also) with how accurately you followed all the steps.
